# whether postfix notation only has a answer?

Tags: data-structures, postfix-notation

```
infix notaion:x=a+b*(c-d+e/f)/(g*h)+i
```

I transform infix into postfix,and I have two answers.I can't sure that which is correct.

```
1.x a b c d - e f / + g h * / * + i + =
2.x a b c d - e f / + * g h * / + i + =
```

I transform post-fix into motion sequence,and found both stacks is empty.
    So, I want to ask whether has possibility of two answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do the evaluation, you'll see that your question comes down to whether     `(b*(c-d+e/f))/(g*h)` is the same as `b*((c-d+e/f)/(g*h))`

The answer is that they're the same. That is:

```
(x*y)/z == x*(y/z)
```